# outlook spell check outbound only

Tags: outlook, spell-checking

In outlook, the admin can force all users to endure a spell check for each email.

Can Outlook be set to enforce spell check *only* for emails that are outbound from the company domain, so that "in-house" emails would not be spell-checked, but all emails going out from the domain would be checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting comes you are seeing probably comes from the standard Outlook group policy which toggles the outlook setting (tools->options->spelling->always check before sending).

Group policies are applied per computer, or per users.  Outlook doesn't appear to offer anything in its configuration pages, and there is nothing in the group policy to make that setting depend on the recipient.

I guess, that it may be possible to build some kind of add-on to accomplish this, but the functionality doesn't appear to exist right now.